# CodeIgniter refresh page only once in a given session

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I have some third-party functionality in my site which tends to not load properly on the first load, but it works perfectly after page refresh. However, if I do a redirect anywhere on the page I get stuck in a loop of redirects. So I am looking for help of how I could escape this redirection loop or somehow just refresh the page once for a given session.

Thanks.

Comment: please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should post your implementation as well.

But...

You can do the following. Add another parameter to user sessions eg. "refreshed" having value either 0 or 1. JS (or PHP functionality) would check the value and depending on the value given would refresh on 0 and set the value as 1. On another check the value would be 1 and would not trigger the redirect/reload.

Furthermore, I'd actually try to fix the page loading on first hand. Implementing a refresh counter would be just masking an issue which would still exist in your project.